# How To count data from many tables and then sum all counts to show

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table Evaluator, Call,  Email in which evalatorID is the primary key and fk to call and email table. I need to show Evaluator name, count of all calls he evaluated and count of all emails he evaluated.  But when I am designing query in access,  it is inner joining and showing only record which is present in both call and email table. 
How to fix that, also at last i want to sum total of all counts to show.
I tried union but it seems like my code has error, it is not running. Can I get the right way to code.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Build aggregate query for Call, build another aggregate query for Email. Then join those queries to Evaluator. Don't use INNER JOIN, use LEFT or RIGHT.

Comment: Each question deserves a separate topic, You should show the group what code you tried already

Comment: SELECT Evaluator.Eval_Name, Count(CallForm.Eval_ID) AS Call, Count(EmailForm.Eval_ID) AS Email, Count(TicketForm.Eval_ID) AS Ticket, Count(WebChat.Eval_ID) AS WebChat
FROM (((Evaluator
 LEFT JOIN CallForm ON Evaluator.Eval_ID = CallForm.Eval_ID))
 LEFT JOIN EmailForm ON Evaluator.Eval_ID = EmailForm.Eval_ID)
  LEFT JOIN TicketForm ON Evaluator.Eval_ID = TicketForm.Eval_ID)
 LEFT JOIN WebChat ON Evaluator.Eval_ID = WebChat.Eval_ID
GROUP BY Evaluator.Eval_Name;

Comment: My code is not working, it only worked for 2 tables and when I added 2 more TicketForm and WebChat it started giving weird results. I am trying to count Each form evalaution done by Evaluator in Every form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using 3 queries to count the calls then emails then calculate the total.  For data I used 4 evaluators where evaluator 1 made 1 call and 1 email while evaluator 4 made 4 calls and 4 emails.  I left the column names at access defaults.
Query 1 counts the calls:

[image]

Query 2 counts the emails:

[image]

Query 3 puts it all together into a query you can use as a record source for a form or report including the total row:

[image]

Here is the resulting recordset based on the sample data:
[image]

No special joins needed.  Hope this answers your question :)
PS: I forgot to mention that you need to add the relationship (arrow) between the tables in the total query. This is because the count calls and count emails tables are based on queries and access doesn't automatically assume how the queries are related.

Comment: Perfect I will try this now

Comment: It is working right for two tables but when adding count of call, email, ticket and webchat, it is again inner joining and showing only record which is present in all tables

Comment: What if Evaluator has only evaluated calls and not Emails then it wont show the record at all.. I want to show all records of Evaluator.

Comment: I recommend creating a new question, but probably create a webchat table then combine that with either the call or email query in the same way the calls and email queries are combined here.